# rails pagination issue with tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabs, pagination

i was wondering if it was possible to only affect one tab when clicking through pagination? im using the will_paginate gem

i have something that looks like...

```
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active span8" id="received">
        <h3>Received Messages</h3>
        <%= render 'received_message_feed'%>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane span8" id="sent">
        <h3>Sent Messages</h3>
        <%= render 'sent_message_feed'%>
      </div>
    </div>
```

which renders...

```
<% if @sent_message_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">   
    <%= render partial: 'shared/message_item', collection: @sent_message_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @sent_message_items %>
<% end %>
```

i have an equivalent received_message partial as well.

in my first block of code, i have 2 tabs, one for my received messages and one for my sent messages. lets say i click on my sent tab and then click on page 2. two problems arise from this.

1. the page refreshes and goes to my received messages tab, which is at first active tab. is there a way to make it go back to sent?
2. the bigger problem, when i click on page 2 while in sent tab, it will also load page 2 on my received tab. is there a way to prevent this?

im not sure how to fix this... help would be appreciated. thank you!

UPDATE.

i winded up using ajax pagination, so then the page doesn't ever reload and problem 1 is circumvented. however problem 2 is still an issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed it.

i winded up using ajax pagination, so then the page doesn't ever reload and problem 1 is circumvented.

and as for problem 2, this saved the day

http://blog.devinterface.com/2011/08/tips-multiple-pagination-with-will_paginate/